# Нужна ли здесь запятая?

Tags: синтаксис

Нужна ли здесь запятая перед словом "прошу"?

*В связи с трудоустройством в арбитражный суд г. прошу направить мне характеристику с места работы по адресу: ................*

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2):

**В связи с трудоустройством в арбитражный суд г....** прошу направить мне характеристику с места работы по адресу:

Обособление обстоятельственных оборотов с производными предлогами **факультативно.** В данном случае оборот можно не обособлять, что связано с его позицией **в начале предложения и деловым стилем** текста.

Обособление оборотов в таких конструкциях возможно в связи с их распространенностью, тогда постановка запятой упрощает понимание текста.